# Adding links on top of view rotating banner

Tags: views, navigation

I am trying to add a link to a page (about us) on top of a view with a rotating banner. There are three banners and i only want the link to appear on top of one of them. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Add a "Global: Text area" to the header of your view that includes the link. This way it will always appear.

[image]